# Coin flip errorless glitch (Python)

Tags: python

Why doesn't this pick heads? The coin looks fine but isn't working, maybe the `randrange` is broken?

```
import random

coin = 0
coin = random.randrange(1,2)
if coin == 1:
    print("tails")
if coin == 2:
    print("heads")
```

Comment: `randrange()` treats its parameters the same way that `range()` does: the starting value is included, the ending value is excluded.  So `randrange(1,2)` cannot return anything other than 1.  You want `random.randint()` instead, that treats both values as inclusive.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write

```
coin = random.randrange(1,3)
```

now coin will be 1 or 2. Let's see an example where we are generating a random integer number within a given range. This example shows all the different forms of random.randrange() function.

```
import random
# Random number between 0 and 15
n1 = random.randrange(16)
print(n1)
# Random number between 10 and 30
n2= random.randrange(10, 31) 
print(n2)
# Random number between 20 and 100 divisible by 2
n3= random.randrange(20, 101, 2)
print(n3)
```

Also you can [see here](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-random-randrange)

Answer (score 0):

Randrange upper bound is non-inclusive